# Nexus 3: "Remote Connection Pending..." for docker hub

Tags: docker, nexus, sonatype

I followed the instructions shown [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=oxCztw5MfAw) for setting up Docker Hub as a proxy repository, but it appears to be stuck with the "Remote Connection Pending..." status. What am I missing?

I'm using Nexus 3 milestone 6. The Dockerfile I am using is here: https://github.com/baselibrary/docker-nexus/blob/801465b9593afcd1533acf020c529767096b223c/3.0/Dockerfile

The video instructions above are effectively the same as the ones listed in the documentation here: https://books.sonatype.com/nexus-book/3.0/reference/docker.html#docker-proxy

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your Nexus Repository Manager might be deployed behind a proxy server and it can therefore not connect to Docker Hub.

Have you tried to pull an image from the repository yet?

Comment: Yeah, that was it. Classic EBKAC.

Answer (score 2):

The "connection pending" message is normal in 3.0m6.  It just means nothing has been downloaded through the proxy repository yet.  Try pulling an image from dockerhub, the status will change once the first file of the image is downloaded.